# HTML5 Video Bookmark - Store current time on click and play

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, html5-video

I am creating a bookmark section for the video using jquery. This is currently static.

On click, I am appending link with the **currentime** in a div. You can then click on the appended links to play the video from that position (e.g. 5th second).

Currently, I am using click function inside click function which is not a good approach. If I remove the second function outside then it does not work as it is unable to find the value.

Could someone please suggest a better way to achieve this? I have created a fiddle link of the code.

**Js Fiddle Link -** https://jsfiddle.net/cp89db4u/1/

**HTML**

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="getTime">Bookmark</a>
<div class="bookmarkList"></div>
```

**JS**

```
var myVid = document.getElementById('videoElement');

$('.getTime').on('click', function() {
    var mycurrentTime = myVid.currentTime;
    $(".bookmarkList").append("<a href='javascript:;' rel='" + mycurrentTime + "' class='bookmarkLink'>" + mycurrentTime + "sec How to get wealth?</a>");

    $('.bookmarkList a').click(function(){
        myVid.currentTime = $(this).attr('rel');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change you Js as below.

```
var myVid = document.getElementById('videoElement');

$('.getTime').on('click', function() {
    var mycurrentTime = myVid.currentTime;
    $(".bookmarkList").append("<a href='javascript:;' rel='" + mycurrentTime + "' class='bookmarkLink'>" + mycurrentTime + "sec - Click to Play</a>");
});

$(document).on('click', ".bookmarkList a", function() {
    myVid.currentTime = $(this).attr('rel');
    myVid.play();
});
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks Praveen :)